# Power iteration method for matrices with complex eigenvectors/values

Tags: numerical-methods

The power iteration method uses these steps:

$$ k=0,1,2,...$$

$$ z_{k+1}=Az_k $$

$$z_{k+1}=\frac{z_{k+1}}{||z_{k+1}||}$$

they say this sequence converges to the eigenvector that corresponds to the dominant eigenvalue. But what if $A$ is a real matrix and all eigenvectors and eigenvalues are complex and $z_0$ is a real vector? What happens in that case?

Comment: What is the exponent method?

Comment: i have replaced "thing" by "sequence"...

Comment: I have also replaced "Exponent method" by its official name : "Power iteration method".

Comment: Complex Eigenvalues of real-valued matrices come in complex conjugated pairs (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem). What does "dominant" mean in this case?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In that case the method will converge to the mean of the eigenvectors.

Let's say $n$ is big. Then $A^nx\approx\lambda x$ for every $x$. Let's take $\mu=\bar{\lambda}$. Obviously $ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\lambda\to\mu$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: This makes almost no sense. In case that there is no single dominant eigenvalue, the iteration will wander inside the subspace composed of the eigenspaces of all eigenvalues of the dominant magnitude. The iterates will not be (eventually, approximately) co-linear, $A(A^nx)\approx \lambda (A^nx)$ is wrong for this situation. There is no obvious estimate for $\lambda$, one could apply linear functionals, but the result will depend on the functional chosen.